# Will thousands of lines of HTML cause performance issues even with multiview in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, performance

I've an ASPX page (Bootstrap based) with a multiview in it, but the actual number of lines of HTML markup in it is very, very huge; more than 4000 lines (plus lots of JS files). But since I am using a multiview it only sends a portion to the user side.

**Will that huge number of lines of `HTML` cause issues (performance-wise) for the server to render the page for the user, even if only part of the HTML is sent due to multiview?**

Comment: your question is not clear. what is the output html in the end?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yea.. Only HTML markup. Not code behind..

Comment: @Emin Am asking about the HTML markup in the design side. I mean the contents in the ASPX page (.aspx). Obviously the final HTML when renders to userside will be minimal since am using multiview. Around 4 views in it. But my worry is about the number of lines in the ASPX page and am asking does that makes any performance issue when rendering.

Comment: If ViewState limit is crossed, it will freeze the page.

Comment: Well put it this way. Since your code is deciding what HTML to render, it is actually based on the power of your server which will be responsible to do the processing on which HTML to send to the browser. Once this is done and HTML is sent to browser, you shouldn't have much problems if your HTML is not thousands of lines long.

Comment: @Emin So that definitely will cause the server to do more to render it even the final rendered HTML is less. isnt it? So will that something be  a performance issue?

Comment: well can't really say without seing the logic of your code. for example.. lets say I am building html in an if--else-- statement and lets assume you have 8000 lines of html to output in each of them. since the matching if statement will be quite fast, the server will not go through each of them and only process the matching if. From here onwards, it is up to you to test it by using some testing tools.